# Is it haram to have a trial marriage in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

A brother and I want to get married.  Yet, my parents (who are not Muslim) are worried I have not found the right man.  There have been a number of divorces in the family.  However, I want to show them we can make it as a couple.  I was wanting to do a trial marriage, (in which you're married but not technically married) for two years before the official ceremony to show them that we will and can work.

Is it haram to have a trial marriage in Islam even if it is to ease a parents' worries?

Comment: Please determine from which sect you expect to get your answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, a person is either single or married. There is no other (middle) state. 
A single person becomes married as soon as marriage agreement ([nikah](/questions/tagged/nikah)) is done.

After establishing Nikah, you may delay the ceremony as long as you want. Ceremony itself is not part of marriage agreement. However, it's best that you let your direct families, close relatives and people around you know that you have established marriage contract.

I suggest that you check with local Masjid (mosque) to get information about minimum requirements for establishing Nikah.

Comment: Based on which sect? Shi'a or Sunni?

Comment: @MohammadHossein, as far as I can see there is no difference regarding the OP's situation between Sunni and Shia views. Please note that the question is not about [tag:nikah-al-mutah].

Comment: I thought the OP means nikah al-mutah by trial marriage.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by trial marriage?

If you are asking if you may marry him without any official ceremony, you could marry him (nikah only without registering the marriage), reveal it to the close relatives and when both of you are comfortable, register the marriage to your respective government.

It is important to note that the boy must pay the mehr before marriage. It is recommended that the mehr is affordable to the man (it could be a gold ring or money he can afford or something that has a value).